# Bootstrap datetimepicker validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap datetimepicker and having a issue with the validation. I have a validation method and also using isNullOrWhitespace in the validation to make sure the value put in is not empty because the textfield allows typing or pasting users own values.

```
<code>
    function isNullOrWhitespace(input) {  
        return !input || input.trim().length < 1;
    }
</code>
```

Weird thing is when I try to click the updown time-selection buttons on the datetimepicker, it fires up the validation as if user is done with the selection. and gets into error: "input.trim is not a function".
So two issues: datetimepicker arrow buttons should not close/behave like the close button. And the validation error.
Any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this:

```
function isNullOrWhitespace(input) {  
  return !input || input.val().trim().length < 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the isNullOrWhitespace(input) method to include a null and length check that fixed my issues. 
Thanks.